# 13.10 Active directory users are not administrator

Tags: permissions, login, active-directory, administrator

In 12.04 I am able to login into Ubuntu with my windows domain user login and also I can have admin privileges to install softwares and apps.

But in 13.10 I am able to login, But I am not an administrator.  Administrator of my machine trying to change my account to 'Administrator' from 'Standard'.  But when I tried to install any app, it says "You are not a 'sudo' user".

Comment: As I understand what you've written, your sysadmin gave you an administrator account on 12.04 but not on 13.10-- so what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I freshly installed 13.10.  But I am not able to make my domain user as Administrator.  Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: in 12.04, I can go to user accounts and change any domain user to Administrator.  But in 13.10 I am not even able to see the list of 'other' users(Basically domain login users).

Comment: Still could not find the solution... :(